# Include файлов из репозитория на GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, devops, ci-cd

Есть два репозитория в GitLab, они лежат в общей папке.

Первый репозиторий содержит микросервис с описанием openApi в openApi.yaml формате.
Второй репозиторий представляет собой архив с документациями по разным проектам. Там тоже есть файл openApi.yaml

Сейчас делая правки в первом микросервисе в openApi.yaml приходится в ручную актуализировать второй репозиторий.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли решения для автоматического include данных из одного репозитория в другой?